# Nuxt3 Form upload file

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3, zod

I have a problem with Nuxt3, I created a page with a file upload form with validation by Zod.
Currently when I put a file in my input files field, it appears and disappears immediately as if the field was reset.

I searched a lot but I can't find a solution to my error.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { any, z } from 'zod'
import type { FormSubmitEvent } from '#ui/types'

const extensionMapping = {
    'fastq': extensionsFastq,
    'fasta': extensionsFasta
}

const initialState = {
  files: <FileList | null> null
}

const state = reactive({ ...initialState });

const schema = z.object({
  files: z.array(
    z.instanceof(File)
  ).min(1, 'At least 1 file is required')
});

type Schema = z.infer<typeof schema>;

const form = ref();

function previewFiles(event: any) {
  console.log(event?.target?.files);
  Object.assign(state, {
    files: (event?.target?.files as HTMLInputElement)?.files
  });
}

function resetForm() {
  Object.assign(state, initialState);
}

async function onSubmit (event: FormSubmitEvent<Schema>) {
  const responseTask = await useSendTask(event.data);
  console.log(responseTask);
}

const extensions = computed(() => {
  return state.algo ? extensionMapping[state.algo as keyof typeof extensionMapping] || [] : [];
});

</script>

<template>
  <div class="h-[85vh] flex items-center justify-center pt-5">
    <div class="bg-slate-100 rounded-xl p-8 mx-5 w-full max-w-screen-xl h-full shadow-md">
      <h1 class="mb-20 text-4xl font-kross tracking-wide leading-none text-black uppercase text-center">Create New Task</h1>


      <UForm ref="form" :schema="schema" :state="state" class="space-y-4" @submit="onSubmit">


        <div class="!mb-15 !mt-10 grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 font-kross">
          <div class="flex justify-center col-span-2">
            <label class="px-4 mb-4 text-xl tracking-wide leading-none text-black text-center">Source File: </label>
            <UFormGroup name="files">
              <UInput @change="previewFiles" type="file" variant="outline" placeholder="Search..." multiple />
            </UFormGroup>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="absolute bottom-[15%] left-0 right-0 z-10 flex justify-center my-10 font-kross font-bold" >
          <UButton type="submit" color="blue" size="xl">
            Submit
          </UButton>

          <UButton variant="outline" color="blue" size="xl" class="ml-2" @click="resetForm">
            Clear
          </UButton>
        </div>

      </UForm>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I looked in several places but I wonder if it's not a problem with the NuxtUi component. I'm going to try using a standard form.
I have other fields in my form but for the sake of simplification I have only included the field that is causing me problems.
I want to respect the structure that I currently use in my page.